# make any installed app debuggable

Tags: android, debugging

I want to debug apps installed in my phone. But before it they must be set debuggable. So I want to know if there is any method to do it on emulator or phone ? And also is it legal to do so ? I tried `adb shell am start -D -n 'package_name'/.'activityname'` command, but it does not open any jdwp port to connect to by debugger, as I see it by running `adb jdwp` command.

Comment: That is not possible, except perhaps on rooted device. Regarding legality, please contact a lawyer that knows the laws for where you live.

Comment: @CommonsWare No problem ! my phone is rooted.

Comment: @CommonsWare Even with not rooted device also, I guess there will be some work around. Cause any one can pull apk from device and then modify it for debugging and install again.